# How has the reputation changed for top users on IPS?

Tags: discussion, reputation

There was a [huge change to reputation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) that took place yesterday. How has this affected the top users on IPS? How has this affected the reputation league?

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone is going to develop a SEDE query (since SEDE only updates at Sundays) but I'm too lazy for that :p

Comment: Ooh smart to use SEDE @Cal. I may do something like that and add it to the answer--good call!

Answer (score 6):

Knowing that certain users on our site may be curious, I grabbed some screenshots yesterday of the reputation league. Below is the before and after (before on the left, after on the right):

[image: rep-league changes]

Comment: Dang I dropped... time to make some sockpuppets

Comment: Related: https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/1143833/top-users-by-reputation-after-change-in-the-weight-of-question-upvote?ScoreThreshold=100

Comment: Related too: https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/1159115/top-users-before-and-after-reputation-change